# Show that $(p,p)$ is not a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

I have to do this exercise where we let $A=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid  n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{R}$. We let $\mathcal{B}$ consist of all open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ together with the sets of the form $(a,b)\setminus(A\cap(a,b))$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b$.

We let $X$ be the topological space obtained from equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathcal{T}$, where $\mathcal{T}$ is the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$.
We need to show that if we let $p:X\to X/A$ denote the projection then $(p,p): X\times X \to X/A\times X/A, (x,y)\mapsto (p(x),p(y))$ is not a quotient map.

I am thinking I have to show that the following does not hold: $V\subseteq X/A\times X/A$ is open if and only if $p^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X/A\times X/A$, but I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: How is $X/A$ defined?

Comment: X/A is a quotient space

Comment: What quotient space? What partition of $X$ defines the quotient space $X/A$?

Comment: @LeeMosher the one that identifies $A$ to a point, partition $\{A\}$ plus all $\{x\}, x \notin A$; it's a standard notation. $X{/}A$ is in this case not Hausdorff.

Comment: Yes, but, I was not so sure of the OP's intention. @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 1):

$(p,p)$ is not quotient as $(p,p)^{-1}[\Delta_Y] = \Delta_X\cup (A\times A)$ ( where $Y=X{/}A$) and the latter set is closed (as $X$ is Hausdorff) and $\Delta_Y$ is *not* closed, as $Y$ is not Hausdorff (as $0$ and $A$ witness the non-regularity of $X$, so their classes witness the non-Hausdorffness of $Y$).

Comment: What is $\Delta_Y$ and $\Delta_X$?

Comment: And how do we know that X is Hausdorff?

Comment: @Sara the diagonal in the square.

Comment: @Sara $X$ is Hausdorff because it’s finer than the usual topology.

Comment: Is $\Delta_X\subseteq X \times X$, and $\Delta_Y\subseteq X/A \times X/A$?

Comment: And how do we know $(p,p)^{-1}[\Delta_Y] = \Delta_X$?

Comment: @Sara yes , $\Delta_X=\{(x,x)\mid x \in X\}$ and similarly for $Y$.  Classic fact: $\Delta_X$ is closed in $X $ iff $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Oh yes, I just saw that we proved that result in class :) How do we know that $A\times A$ is closed?

Comment: @Sara $A$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: Would X be $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Sara no $X$ is the adapted finer topology. That’s the whole point.